# Изменение строки abcd --> A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd

Tags: javascript

Пишу функцию, которая изменяет строку:

```
accum("abcd");    // "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
accum("RqaEzty"); // "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
accum("cwAt");    // "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
```

Не пойму, какой метод вставить между `split('').join('')`, чтобы js прибавлял новый символ каждому следующему символу:

```js
const accum = (str) => str
  .split(' ')
  .map(word => word.split('').join('-'))
  .join(' ');

console.log(accum('abcd'));
```

Подозреваю, что мой алгоритм неверный, и здесь можно было бы легко решить замыканиями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тоже это задание на `CodeWars` решал.
Поможет [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) и текущий индекс в массиве:

```js
const accum = str => str
  .split('')
  .map((ch, i) => (ch = ch.toLowerCase().repeat(i + 1)) && ch.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ch.slice(1))
  .join('-');

console.log(accum("abcd"));    // "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
console.log(accum("RqaEzty")); // "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
console.log(accum("cwAt"));    // "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Подход (с `join` и `split`) у вас верный, но реализовано не так, как нужно.

Сначала нужно рассмотреть две вещи, как из `'a'` получить `axN` (символ `а`, повторенный N раз). И как сделать все символы в строке строчными, а первый - прописным (большим).

1. Самый простой способ, использовать конструкцию:

`Array(N + 1).join('a')`.

*Надо отметить, что длина массива будет N+1, а количество полученных символов `a` только N, так как `Array.join` помещает аргумент (в нашем случае символ `a`) между массивом элементов, которые в данном примере `undefined`.*

2. Для приведения строки в "строчный" вид нужно использовать функции `String.prototype.toUpperCase()` и `String.prototype.toLowerCase()`. Так как нужно сделать "большой" только первый символ, лучше написать отдельную функцию.

Собственно решение:

```js
//первый символ делаем прописным
const capitalizeFirstLetter = (s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)

const accum = (str) => str
  .split('') // разбиваем исходную строку на массив по символу
  .map((word, i) => capitalizeFirstLetter(Array(i+2).join(word).toLowerCase()))
  .join('-'); // объединяем полученные фрагменты (элементы массива)

// map(...) - копируем символ `i+2` раза, т.к. индекс массива начинается с 0, 
// приводим все к нижнему регистру, а потом первый символ к верхнему.


console.log(accum('abcd'));    // "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
console.log(accum('RqaEzty')); // "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
console.log(accum('cwAt'));    // "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const accum = (str) => str
  .split(' ')
  .map(
        word => word.split('')
       .map(function(w,i){ return w.repeat(i+1) })
      .join('-')
       )
  .join(' ');

console.log(accum('dsdsd Rffr  dssds')); //d-ss-ddd-ssss-ddddd R-ff-fff-rrrr  d-ss-sss-dddd-sssss
```

возможно также

```
          .map(function(w,i){ return new Array(i + 2).join(w); }) //здесь происходит вся магия дублирования контента. создается пустой массив и объединяется вашими символами, т.е. нужен массив длиной +1. Так как первый элемент массива имеет индекс 0, то ещё +1
```